# Prevent malfunction of scroll caused due to double-click and failing to detect mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have made a **<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGrte/)</kbd>** in which the div can be scrolled by click-move on the div body(click/mousedown on the body of div and move mouse pointer Left/Right to scroll)

**HTML**

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.slide').width($('#slides').width()/3).height($('#slides').height());

var chk_click = false;
var downX;
var currentScroll=$('#slides').scrollLeft();

$('#slides').mousedown(function(event){
    chk_click = true;
    downX=event.clientX;
    currentScroll=$('#slides').scrollLeft();
}).mouseup(function(){
    chk_click = false;
});

$('#slides').mousemove(function(event){
    if(chk_click == false){}
    else{
    var moveX=event.clientX;
    $('#slides').scrollLeft((downX-moveX)+currentScroll);
    }
});
```

It works correctly as long as the I do one click and move mouse to scroll. But after doing (double click+release) and then if I click-move to scroll it doesnt scroll and on mouseup scrolls when actually it shouldn't scroll.

When I add `event.preventDefault();`(**<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGrte/1/)</kbd>**) for `$('#slides').mousedown(function(event){ ... });` it works but fails to detect mouseup outside the window/area of the document.

I hope all are able to understand what I am asking.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself.Instead of adding mouseup to `#slides` I added it to `window` and with this edit in the 2nd fiddle works perfectly:

### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/BWPZE/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work as expected in both the fiddles you provided (in chrome 32.0.1700.77).

Click and drag moves the slider. 
Double click has no effect. 
Double click, hold and drag moves the slider.

I do however understand your problem with mouseup not registering when outside of the window.

To solve this you could listen for the mouseup event on 'body' or another parent container instead of the slider window.

```
$('body').mouseup(function(){
    chk_click = false;
});
```

see [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjeb2/1/)

note: When the mouseup happens outside of the jsfiddle preview window this is outside of the 'body' of that page (it's an iframe). I have made the slider smaller to demonstrate that mouseup outside of the slider window but inside the body is captured.

Comment: This doesnt solve my problem.But thanks for answering and welcome to stackoverflow